# Авторизация в БД с использованием сервлетов

Tags: java, sql-server, servlet

У меня есть класс для формирования соединения с БД

```
public class MyConnection {

    private static Connection con;

    private static String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName =FininceAnalysis";
    private static String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    private static String user = "Admin";
    private static String password = "1234";

    public  MyConnection(){}

    public static Connection openConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException{

        if(con==null){

            Class.forName(driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        }

        return con;

    }

    public static void closeConnection()throws SQLException{

         if(con!=null){

            con.close();
        }
            con = null;
} }
```

Он вызывается в других сервлетах для установления соединения с  БД 
Сервлеты такого типа

```
@WebServlet(name = "DayIndex", urlPatterns = {"/DayIndex"})public class DayIndex extends HttpServlet {public String getTable()throws Exception{


        String sql =  "SELECT [dbo].[Report_Count_Index].[ID_Index], [dbo].[Report_Count_Index].Data, [dbo].[Index_Table].Name,[dbo].[Report_Count_Index].[Varible],[dbo].[Index_Table].Max,[dbo].[Index_Table].Min,[dbo].[Index_Table].Description, [dbo].[Report_Count_Index].Recomendation,    [dbo].[Report_Count_Index].Day_of_week,[dbo].[Report_Count_Index].Day_of_Mounth,[dbo].[Report_Count_Index].Day_of_Year,[dbo].[Report_Count_Index].Name_Mounth,[dbo].[Report_Count_Index].Number_Mounth,[dbo].[Report_Count_Index].Quater_Current,[dbo].[Report_Count_Index].Week_of_year,[dbo].[Report_Count_Index].Year_Current,  [dbo].[Type_Dim].Name  as 'Index_Kind', [dbo].[Sorce_Dim].Name as 'Sorce', [dbo].[Unit_Dim].Name as 'Unit',[dbo].[Sorce_Dim].Code  FROM [dbo].[Report_Count_Index]   INNER JOIN [dbo].[Index_Table]  ON [dbo].[Report_Count_Index].[ID_Index]=[dbo].[Index_Table].[ID_Index]  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Type_Dim]  ON [dbo].Type_Dim.ID_Type=[dbo].[Index_Table].ID_Type  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Unit_Dim]  ON [dbo].[Unit_Dim].ID_Unit=[dbo].[Index_Table].ID_Unit  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Sorce_Dim]  ON [dbo].[Sorce_Dim].ID_Sorce=[dbo].[Index_Table].ID_Unit  WHERE [dbo].[Report_Count_Index].Data>=DATEADD(DAY,-1, CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(),112)) AND [dbo].[Report_Count_Index].Data<CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(),112)  ORDER BY [dbo].[Report_Count_Index].[ID_Index]  ";

        Statement st = MyConnection.openConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

       ArrayList<IndexReportMethods>dataTableOne = new ArrayList<IndexReportMethods>();
         while (rs.next()) {
    dataTableOne.add(new IndexReportMethods(rs.getInt("ID_Index"),
            rs.getString("Data"),rs.getString("Name"),rs.getFloat("Varible"),rs.getFloat("Max"),
            rs.getFloat("Min"), rs.getString("Description"),rs.getString("Recomendation"),
            rs.getString("Day_of_week"), rs.getInt("Day_of_Mounth"), rs.getInt("Day_of_Year"),
            rs.getString("Name_Mounth"), rs.getInt("Number_Mounth"), rs.getInt("Quater_Current"),
            rs.getInt("Week_of_year"), rs.getInt("Year_Current"), rs.getString("Index_Kind"),
            rs.getString("Sorce"), rs.getString("Unit"), rs.getString("Code")

            ));          
            }
        return new Gson().toJson(dataTableOne);

    }



protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
   //response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try{

        out.println(getTable());

    }

    catch(Exception e){
        out.println("Error"+e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        out.close();

    }


}


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}


@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}}
```

Необходимо создать сервлет для авторизации в БД, т.е ввожу логин и пароль на форме и происходит установка соединения с БД, и другие сервлеты должны устанавливать соединение по этим параметрам. Возможно ли это вообще? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Если это не какой-то встраиваемый сервер, то зачем это всё городить, когда есть стандартное решение. Описано в интернете много раз.

Comment: уточните вопрос, вы хотите знать как передавать параметры между сервлетами?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Vaysman что-то вроде этого. Пользователь проходит авторизацию с БД    private static String user = "Admin";
    private static String password = "1234"; Эти данные должны заполнятся при авторизации, а затем их должен использовать каждый сервлет при подключении к БД.

Comment: @Sergey а можете подробнее рассказать про это это решение,пожалуйста

Comment: Это длинный рассказ. Почитайте это что ли http://devcolibri.com/4575. Кроме шага 6. Шаг 6 специфический для конкретного сервера приложений. Для tomcat одно, для glassfish другое. Вот ещё статья http://onedeveloper.ru/article?id=10 для glassfish. Но если читаете по аглицки, то лучше искать аглицкие материалы. Там лучше всё описано. Опять таки стандартные руководства по своему серверу приложений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует несколько вариантов решения этой задачи:

1. Поместить параметры в сессию

   ```
   request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
   ```

   И потом читать их от туда

   ```
   String user = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
   ```

   Эти параметры будут доступны пока существует сессия.
2. Поместить параметры в контекст servlet

   ```
   getServletConfig().getServletContext().setAttribute("user", user);
   ```

   И потом читать их от туда

   ```
   String user = (String) getServletConfig().getServletContext().getAttribute("user");
   ```

   Эти параметры будет доступны пока их не уберут из контекста

   ```
   getServletConfig().getServletContext().removeAttribute("user");
   ```